# Which Google Cloud Function Quota am I Exceeding?

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, quota

I'm a newbie to GCF, using Python make some API requests and ETL some data to our warehouse via Fivetran. I can set start/end date parameters in my API call to limit the amount of data I get in each HTTP request.

After lots of testing, I've determined that by setting start/end date parameters to keep my total HTTP request results < 9.5 MB my code executes properly. As soon as I exceed ~ 9.5 MB my code fails.

I've read the GCF Docs and see that there are several resource quotas around 10 MB and I'm assuming that I've exceeded one of these, but I'm not entirely sure which one.

I don't think I'm exceeding the HTTP request or response sizes as I'm paginating my requests and none of them should be near 10 MB. My function is relatively small, I don't see how I could be exceeding the max function memory quota. So that leaves "Max event size for background functions". I've tried to get more details about that but can't find any.

And, if I am exceeding a quota like max event size, and since "return" tells GCF that my function should end, is there any way to do multiple "returns" or chunk up the final > 9.5 MB result?

As far as I can tell, the error occurs in the final step in my code:

```
return assemble_response_json(insert), 200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
```

When the size of the JSON I'm trying to send to Fivetran is less than 9.5 MB, my code executes correctly and returns the properly-formatted JSON. When the JSON I try to send to Fivetran is greater than ~ 9.5 MB my code returns the following error:

"Function execution took 6868 ms, finished with status: 'response error'"

Comment: How are you measuring the size of your response here?

Comment: Since posting, I've imported sys and used the following code to display the HTTP response's size in bytes:

`sys.getsizeof(assemble_response_json(insert))`

That returns a size around 10.5 MB, so I'm definitely exceeding a 10 MB  quota. As the first commenter suggested, this seems to be exceeding the "Max uncompressed HTTP response size" quota. I'm not searching for ways to either compress the response or chunk it up so it can be fed to Fivetran for ETL.

Comment: Should say I'm **now** searching for ways to compress the response or chunk it up.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas), the maximum size of the payload for both requests and responses is 10MB.  You will have to keep the size of your response under that limit.

Comment: So even though the paginated results of my API GET requests each come in under the 10 MB quota, is the problem that when they are all lumped together as JSON to be fed to Fivetran that file size is > 10 MB? And would that be exceeding the "Max event size for background functions" quota, or a different one?

Comment: You're exceeding the "Max uncompressed HTTP response size".